# animating a scatterplot of data

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

(I'm new to html5... so use small words)

I'm trying to animate a scatterplot of some data (the points move over time).

Right now, I have a series of context.arc() with the specific coordinates and can create one "frame" of the animation.

My initial thought is to use a strategy similar to an animated gif: create a sequence of frames and plot them sequentially with some delay in-between.

Is this a viable approach? If so, how should I delay the rendering? My initial reading indicates that there is no real sleep function, so I'm wondering if this strategy is bad.

(also, any points to software to create html5 markup for scatterplot instead of my low-level coding would be great)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the `canvas` element is filled from JavaScript you can use the `setTimeout` or `setInterval` functions, [see here](http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/tutorials/javascript/timers) for more help with JavaScript timers. This would allow you to draw each frame after a predetermined amount of time. An object orientated language such as SVG would probably be more appropriate though, so you can move elements rather than draw over them; most browsers advertising themselves to be "HTML5 compatible" should have reasonable support for it.

Comment: That was my thought. However, this doesn't seem to work:

   function circle(){
        context.beginPath();
       <!--...-->
    }

    function frame1(){
        circle(.1, .2);
        circle(.6, .7);
    }
    function frame2(){
        circle(.3, .8);
        circle(.8, .2);
    }

   setTimeout("frame1()",3000);
   setTimeout("frame2()",3000);

but

    frame1();
    frame2();

does.

Comment: @topepo That is because `setTimeout(frame1()...)` and `setTimeout(frame2()...)` are both being called at the same time - whenever that block of code executes, with a delay of three seconds. Try changing the delay in calling your second frame to 3020 milliseconds, assuming you want your animation to run at 50fps.

Comment: Thanks. I had the good sense to use chrome and its debugger. This issue appears to be that "Uncaught ReferenceError: frame1 is not defined" when using setTimeout("frame1()", 3000). However, replacing this with frame1() does produce the circles, so I'm stumped.

Comment: @topepo Perhaps your problem is related to this? [MDN setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout#Passing_string_literals). If you have embedded functions then they may be hidden from the window. Otherwise what fragments you have included of your code appear fine to me too...

Comment: Bingo. I changed my definitions from "function frame1(){" to "frame1 = function(){" and everything is good. Thanks for your help.